# Why should I call a BERT module instance rather than the forward method?

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to extract vector-representations of text using BERT in the transformers libray, and have stumbled on the following part of the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertmodel) for the "BERTModel" class:

[image]

Can anybody explain this in more detail? A forward-pass makes intuitive sense to me (am trying to get final hidden states after all), and I can't find any additional information on what "pre and post processing" means in this context.

Thanks up front!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just general advice concerning working with PyTorch `Module`'s. The `transformers` modules are `nn.Module`s, and they require a `forward` method. However, one should not call `model.forward()` manually but instead call `model()`. The reason is that PyTorch does some stuff under the hood when just calling the Module. You can find that in [the source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module).

```py
def __call__(self, *input, **kwargs):
    for hook in self._forward_pre_hooks.values():
        result = hook(self, input)
        if result is not None:
            if not isinstance(result, tuple):
                result = (result,)
            input = result
    if torch._C._get_tracing_state():
        result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    else:
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
        hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
        if hook_result is not None:
            result = hook_result
    if len(self._backward_hooks) > 0:
        var = result
        while not isinstance(var, torch.Tensor):
            if isinstance(var, dict):
                var = next((v for v in var.values() if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor)))
            else:
                var = var[0]
        grad_fn = var.grad_fn
        if grad_fn is not None:
            for hook in self._backward_hooks.values():
                wrapper = functools.partial(hook, self)
                functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, hook)
                grad_fn.register_hook(wrapper)
    return result
```

You'll see that `forward` is called when necessary.

Comment: Hi Bram - thanks for the quick reply. Already helps a bunch to have a quite definitive answer on whether to use the Module call or the forward call. I do however have to admit that the above code is mostly gibberish to me. Would it be possible for you to summarize at a high level  what the "stuff under the hood" is? Otherwise I'll go hunting :-)

Comment: When you build your model, you can also register [(pre_)hooks](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_forward_pre_hook) and backward_hooks. They modify the input before/after going through the model or before/after backprop. I have never used those. The code also accounts for [tracing](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#torch.jit.trace).